# Why am I getting a Module Parse Failed Error when running NuxtJS App in SSR Mode?

Tags: vue.js, webpack, nuxt.js

I have a NUXTJS (2.13.3) that has been running fine in spa client mode. I recently decided to switch it to SSR mode. The project builds fine, but when I browse to it in the browser I receive the following error:

Module parse failed: Unexpected token (135:43) File was processed with these loaders: * ./node_modules/babel-loader/lib/index.js You may need an additional loader to handle the result of these loaders. | for (const field in error.errors) { | if (!Array.isArray(error.errors[field])) { > errorMessages += error.detail ?? error.title; | break; | } else {

```
server.js:10208:7
Object../components/forms/validators.js
server.js:27:30
__webpack_require__
server.js:11320:89
Module../node_modules/babel-loader/lib/index.js?!./node_modules/@nuxt/components/dist/loader.js?!./node_modules/vue-loader/lib/index.js?!./components/app/send.vue?vue&type=script&lang=js&
server.js:27:30
__webpack_require__
server.js:9605:247
Module../components/app/send.vue?vue&type=script&lang=js&
server.js:27:30
__webpack_require__
server.js:9566:92
Module../components/app/send.vue
server.js:27:30
__webpack_require__
```

This is kind of hard to determine where the issue might be? Any suggestions?

Thanks!

Comment: Can you post line 135 of the affected file please?

Comment: @RazRonen which one would be the affected file? There are several files referenced above in the error. validators.js?

Comment: Is this the complete error? Its probably the file that contains this strin: `errorMessages += error.detail ?? error.title; | break; `

Comment: Can you also please post the loaders section of your webpack configuration?

Comment: for (const field in error.errors) { if (!Array.isArray(error.errors[field])) { errorMessages += error.detail ?? error.title break } else { errorMessages += field + ': ' + error.errors[field] + '<br/>' } }

Comment: where did you post it?

Comment: Sorry, just posted it above, with respect to webpack configuration, I am using NuxtJS, so it auto generates the webback config and I am not customizing it.

Comment: @RazRonen I posted the line in question above.

Answer (score 0):

It's a common error when you import and add some module or some class in some dependencies. Check where you add some module, that haven't be here. That error says that process start working,  get some link and start process with this package, and because this package doesn't have required properties -- it falls. But all packages is OK,  false spreads from only first error package,  to all another packages